# rotating portrait image via canvas not properly center (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, orientation

I'm creating a hybrid mobile app where the user can take photo from their phone and then upload it to a server. The problem that I am facing is that when user takes a portrait image, the image is not properly centered and it leaves a black border beside it.

Here is an example of a portrait photo taken from my app:
[Uploaded Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuNzA.jpg)

Below is the code that I am using to rotate the image based on orientation and compress it

```
function processFile(dataURL, fileType, orientation) {

var maxWidth = 800;
var maxHeight = 600;

var image = new Image();
image.src = dataURL;

image.onload = function () {
    var width = image.width;
    var height = image.height;
    var shouldResize = (width > maxWidth) || (height > maxHeight);

    if (!shouldResize) {
        dataURL = dataURL.substring(dataURL.indexOf(',')+1);

        return;
    }


    var newWidth;
    var newHeight;

    if (width > height) {
        newHeight = height * (maxWidth / width);
        newWidth = maxWidth;
    } else {
        newWidth = width * (maxHeight / height);
        newHeight = maxHeight;
    }

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

    canvas.width = newWidth;
    canvas.height = newHeight;

    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    console.log("orientation here: "+orientation);
   switch(orientation){
case 2:
    // horizontal flip
    context.translate(canvas.width, 0);
    context.scale(-1, 1);
    break;
case 3:
    // 180° rotate left
    context.translate(canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.rotate(Math.PI);
    break;
case 4:
    // vertical flip
    context.translate(0, canvas.height);
    context.scale(1, -1);
    break;
case 5:
    // vertical flip + 90 rotate right
    context.rotate(0.5 * Math.PI);
    context.scale(1, -1);
    break;
case 6:
    // 90° rotate right
    context.rotate(0.5 * Math.PI);
    context.translate(0, -canvas.height);
    break;
case 7:
    // horizontal flip + 90 rotate right
    context.rotate(0.5 * Math.PI);
    context.translate(canvas.width, -canvas.height);
    context.scale(-1, 1);
    break;
case 8:
    // 90° rotate left
    context.rotate(-0.5 * Math.PI);
    context.translate(-canvas.width, 0);
    break;
}

      context.drawImage(this, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);



        dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(fileType,0.7);
        dataURL = dataURL.substring(dataURL.indexOf(',')+1);
        console.log("dataURL here: "+dataURL);

    };

    image.onerror = function () {
        alert('image error');
    };
}
```

I would really appreciate if somebody can tell me what i'm doing wrong with my code and how to fix it.

Thanks in advanced

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code, that means something is wrong on the server side. My bet is you've assumed on the server that coming image is of 800 X 600 size, where it's different in case resizing is done.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? I'm scratching my head to make it done properly.

Comment: Hi, I apologize as I did not see the rotation part of your question, yes there are a few things incorrect in the program, I'll post an answer today.

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to use **context.save()** and **context.restore()**.
Apart from that there are a few things

1. There is no need to load image on every call to processFile.
2. drawImage takes [9 arguments](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp). Many of these are optional. First is image. From second to fifth is the clipping region of image. From sixth to ninth is drawing region of canvas. So you can't use `context.drawImage(this, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);`
    You have to use `context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, x, y, newWidth, newHeight);`
3. Also there's no need to create canvas element every time processFile() is called, one hidden canvas can be used for all the processing.
4. Image's src attribute should be assigned after onload/onerror events are bound otherwise there's a possibility that they will not get a chance to run.

Here is the working JsFiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/48qfy71a/

I have removed the shouldResize check condition, please add it as you need.
Also I have created an image on canvas to give as input to the program as I wasn't able to find third party images which will not taint canvas.

You can use any image you need as below

```
//instead of
var imageUrl = createImageUrl();
// use this
var imageUrl = "test.jpg";
```

Here's the code for backup

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <strong>Orientation </strong><select id="selectOption">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
        </select><br/>
        <canvas id="testCanvas" width="800", height="600" style="border:1px solid red;"></canvas>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Script**

```
//var imageUrl = "test.jpg";
var imageUrl = createImageUrl();

function createImageUrl() {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = 800;
    canvas.height = 600;
    context.font = 'italic 60pt Calibri';
    context.textAlign = 'center';
    context.fillText('Hello World!', canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);

    return canvas.toDataURL("jpg", 0.7);
}

document.getElementById("selectOption").onchange = function () {
    processFile("jpg", parseInt(this.value));
}

var image = new Image();

image.onload = function () { processFile("jpg", 1);};
image.onerror = function() {
    alert('image error');
};
image.src = imageUrl;

function processFile(fileType, orientation) {

    var maxWidth = 800;
    var maxHeight = 600;

    var width = image.width;
    var height = image.height;
    var shouldResize = (width > maxWidth) || (height > maxHeight);

    var canvas = document.getElementById('testCanvas');

    /*if (!shouldResize) {
        dataURL = dataURL.substring(dataURL.indexOf(',') + 1);

        return;
    }*/

    var newWidth;
    var newHeight;

    if (width > height) {
        newHeight = height * (maxWidth / width);
        newWidth = maxWidth;
    } else {
        newWidth = width * (maxHeight / height);
        newHeight = maxHeight;
    }

    canvas.width = newWidth;
    canvas.height = newHeight;

    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    console.log("orientation here: " + orientation);
    context.save();
    switch (orientation) {
        case 2:
            // horizontal flip
            context.translate(newWidth, 0);
            context.scale(-1, 1);
            drawScalledImage(0, 0);
            break;
        case 3:
            // 180° rotate left
            context.translate(canvas.width, canvas.height);
            context.rotate(Math.PI);
            drawScalledImage(0, 0);
            context.translate(-canvas.width, -canvas.height);
            break;
        case 4:
            // vertical flip
            context.translate(0, newHeight);
            context.scale(1, -1);
            drawScalledImage(0, 0);
            break;
        case 5:
            // vertical flip + 90 rotate right
            context.translate(newWidth / 2, newHeight / 2);
            context.rotate(0.5 * Math.PI);
            context.scale(1,-1);
            drawScalledImage(-newWidth / 2, -newHeight / 2);
            break;
        case 6:
            // 90° rotate right
            context.translate(newWidth / 2, newHeight / 2);
            context.rotate(0.5 * Math.PI);
            drawScalledImage(-newWidth / 2, -newHeight / 2);
            break;
        case 7:
            // horizontal flip + 90 rotate right
            context.translate(newWidth / 2, newHeight / 2);
            context.rotate(0.5 * Math.PI);
            context.scale(-1,1);
            drawScalledImage(-newWidth / 2, -newHeight / 2);
            break;
        case 8:
            // 90° rotate left
            context.translate(newWidth / 2, newHeight / 2);
            context.rotate(-0.5 * Math.PI);
            drawScalledImage(-newWidth / 2, -newHeight / 2);
            context.rotate(0.5 * Math.PI);
            context.translate(-newWidth / 2, -newHeight / 2);
            break;
        default:
            drawScalledImage(0, 0);
            break;
    }

    function drawScalledImage(x,y) {
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, x, y, newWidth, newHeight);
    }
    context.restore();

    window.context = context;
    var base64Image = canvas.toDataURL(fileType, 0.7);
    base64Image = base64Image.substring(base64Image.indexOf(',') + 1);

    //console.log("dataURL here: " + dataURL);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this sir. With a little modification. i'm able to rotate it properly. Thanks!!!